# How to run specific javascript files to update gui

Tags: javascript, django, highcharts

I am using Django. My goal is to have a specific Highcharts chart displayed along with a list of different charts down the left side of the webpage. When each link (or button, or whatever) is clicked on the left side, the currently displayed chart will be replaced with whichever one was clicked.

To do this, each highcharts chart is contained within its own javascript file. The charts work correctly by just adding them into a div tag with their id. But I don't know how to swap between them when a button is clicked.

Here's what i've got so far:
HTML file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "basic_bar.js" %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "complex_bar.js" %}"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="showBasic"></div>
        <input class="showBasic" type="button" value="Basic Chart" onclick="showBasic();"/>
        <input class="showComplex" type="button" value="Complex Chart" onclick="showComplex();"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a small part of the basic highcharts javascript file:

```
$(function () {
    $('#showBasic').highcharts({
        //chart code
    });
});
```

Currently, the basic chart is displayed when the page loads because it is referenced in the div tag with the id="showBasic". What I don't know how to do is use the buttons to swap between displaying the basic or complex chart. I presume I need to somehow change the div id="showBasic to instead be div id="showComplex"

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to have both div's on your page, and use show/hide to make sure that only one is displayed at a time. The loaded javascript will render both highcharts, and you can simply hide or show the correct one:

```
// Show Basic chart.
$('#showBasic').show();
$('#showComplex').hide();
```

or

```
// Show Complexchart.
$('#showBasic').hide();
$('#showComplex').show();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @SteveP. However wouldn't that mean that I would have to initially have both charts displayed, each in their own div. Then by clicking the buttons I could show/hide a particular chart? Im just not sure I understand how I would only display one of the charts initially (ie: before any buttons are clicked). Thanks.

Comment: oh nevermind, I just figured out a way. I can add a script tag inside each div which would default the charts to hidden. Thanks again.

Comment: You can hide the div's initial state using css as well #showBasic { visibility: hidden; }. You could also create a css class to hide them: .hidden {  display:none;} and give you div the hidden class.